# Moving from static JOIN TABLE to using SELECT to perform JOIN

Tags: mysql, select, join, syntax

I have two tables, one is for reviews (id, title, cover_art, text, rating, updated) and the other is for artists (id, artist_name).

I have a column for the artist id in the reviews table.

Up until earlier today I simply accessed a table that joined both tables, but it turns out this will cause problems going forwards.

Here's an example of where the JOIN code needs to go:

```
mysql_select_db($database_em, $em);
$query_getDisplay = "SELECT news.title, news.cover_art, news.blog_entry, news.rating, DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%M %e, %Y') AS formatted FROM news ORDER BY news.updated DESC     LIMIT 1"; 
$getDisplay = mysql_query($query_getDisplay, $em) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getDisplay = mysql_fetch_assoc($getDisplay);
$totalRows_getDisplay = mysql_num_rows($getDisplay);
```

And here's the JOIN that I'd like to fit in there:

```
artists.artists_name
FROM   news JOIN artists ON artists.id = news.artistid
```

But wherever I put it in the place I think it should go (between news.rating, and DATE_FORMAT following it with a comma) the page breaks and I get this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(news.updated, '%M %e, %Y') AS formatted FROM news ORDER BY news.updated DESC LI' at line 2
```

Here's the whole code minus the sql injection switch code I have in the header. I've tried adding the JOIN code between every instance of news.rating, and DATE_FORMAT and various other ideas as well as look through stackoverflow's knowledge base (btw this is based on code I used in a David Powers tutorial so most of it may even be redundant)

```
mysql_select_db($database_em, $em);
$query_getArchives = "SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%M %Y') AS archive,     DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%Y-%m') AS link FROM news ORDER BY news.updated DESC";
$getArchives = mysql_query($query_getArchives, $em) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getArchives = mysql_fetch_assoc($getArchives);
$totalRows_getArchives = mysql_num_rows($getArchives);

mysql_select_db($database_em, $em);
$query_getRecent = "SELECT news.post_id, news.title FROM news ORDER BY news.updated DESC LIMIT 20";
$getRecent = mysql_query($query_getRecent, $em) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getRecent = mysql_fetch_assoc($getRecent);
$totalRows_getRecent = mysql_num_rows($getRecent);

mysql_select_db($database_em, $em);
$query_getDisplay = "SELECT news.title, news.cover_art, news.blog_entry, news.rating, artists.artists_name
FROM   news JOIN artists ON artists.id = news.artistid, DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%M %e, %Y') AS formatted FROM news ORDER BY news.updated DESC LIMIT 1"; 
$getDisplay = mysql_query($query_getDisplay, $em) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getDisplay = mysql_fetch_assoc($getDisplay);
$totalRows_getDisplay = mysql_num_rows($getDisplay);

$var1_getDisplay2 = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['archive'])) {
$var1_getDisplay2 = $_GET['archive'];
$query_getDisplay = sprintf("SELECT news.blog_entry, news.cover_art, news.rating, DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%%M %%e, %%Y') AS formatted FROM news WHERE DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%%Y-%%m') = %s ORDER BY news.updated DESC", GetSQLValueString($var1_getDisplay2, "text"));
} elseif (isset($_GET['post_id'])) {
$var2_getDisplay3 = $_GET['post_id'];
$query_getDisplay = sprintf("SELECT news.title, news.cover_art, news.blog_entry, news.rating, DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%%M %%e, %%Y') AS formatted FROM news WHERE news.post_id = %s", GetSQLValueString($var2_getDisplay3, "int"));
} else {
$query_getDisplay = "SELECT news.title, news.cover_art, news.blog_entry, news.rating, DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%M %e, %Y') AS formatted FROM news ORDER BY news.updated DESC LIMIT 3";
}
$getDisplay = mysql_query($query_getDisplay, $em) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getDisplay = mysql_fetch_assoc($getDisplay);
$totalRows_getDisplay = mysql_num_rows($getDisplay);
?>
```

BTW here's the code in the actual page:

```
<!-- start center column include -->
<div class="center_column">
<div class="center_column_title">
    <?php echo date('H:i:s'); ?> GMT
</div>
<div id="blog_posts">
  <?php do { ?>
    <h2><?php echo $row_getDisplay['title']; ?></h2>
    <h3><?php echo $row_getDisplay['artists_name']; ?></h3>
    <p class="cover_art"><img src="<?php echo $row_getDisplay['cover_art']; ?>" /></p>
    <p class="updated">Updated <?php echo $row_getDisplay['formatted']; ?></p>
    <p class="blog_entry"><?php echo nl2br($row_getDisplay['blog_entry']); ?></p>
    <p class="blog_rating">Rating - <?php echo $row_getDisplay['rating']; ?> (out of a possible 1,000,000)</p>
    <?php } while ($row_getDisplay = mysql_fetch_assoc($getDisplay)); ?>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<!-- end center column include -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 FROM clauses here:

```
mysql_select_db($database_em, $em);
$query_getDisplay = "SELECT news.title, news.cover_art, news.blog_entry, news.rating, artists.artists_name
FROM   news JOIN artists ON artists.id = news.artistid, DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%M %e, %Y') AS formatted FROM news ORDER BY news.updated DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Change it to:

```
mysql_select_db($database_em, $em);
$query_getDisplay = "SELECT news.title, news.cover_art, news.blog_entry, news.rating, artists.artists_name, DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%M %e, %Y') AS formatted
FROM   news JOIN artists ON artists.id = news.artistid ORDER BY news.updated DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Nice, it doesn't break now, but the artists_name isn't showing up in the blog title. Maybe there's another place the join code needs to go.

Comment: OH wait - I see what you mean. Let me fix the other instance(s)

Comment: Thank you, worked great. I just added it to a couple other places and it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest if you table is relational then use the foreign key to the other table primary key so that you can use the query join table....

but you can still join the table...

$query = "SELECT * FROM Review LEFT OUTER JOIN Artist";
anyway let's me see the site... :D

Comment: I would but it's in MAMP on my laptop. I'll let you know when it's online though.

So you think I should put $query = "SELECT * FROM Review LEFT OUTER JOIN Artist"; on the line below every instance of $query_getDisplay = "SELECT news.title, news.cover_art, news.blog_entry, news.rating, artists.artists_name
FROM   news JOIN artists ON artists.id = news.artistid, DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%M %e, %Y') AS formatted FROM news ORDER BY news.updated DESC LIMIT 1";